# picocli : redirect stdout and stderr to logger

Tags: picocli

What is the correct/easiest way to redirect output (out/err) from `.execute()` or `.parseArgs()` to a logger (`org.slf4j.Logger`)?

*(Production processes are often executed by a scheduler with output to application-specific log files. And stdout/err, if not redirected, gets dumped in the scheduler/server log - which is not appropriate. Hence this question.)*

I have something like this:

```java
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApp.class);
    // ...
    new CommandLine(new MyApp())
      .setOut(new LoggerWriter(logger, Level.INFO)
      .setErr(new LoggerWriter(logger, Level.ERROR)
      .execute(args);
    // ...
```

where the `LoggerWriter` class is **inspired** from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/logging/util/LoggerWriter.java.html).